# How to display metadata on Sharepoint Modern page?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts

I'm looking for a way to display CreatedBy, ModifiedBy, Created and Modified metadata on a Sharepoint Modern page. The "Page Properties" webpart displays custom metadata but not the ones mentioned. Can't find any GitHub repositories either to create a simple SPFx. Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks!
Bo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a sample for you in my repo at https://github.com/hugoabernier/react-pagemetadata.

[image: Preview]

Take a look and feel free to ask if you have any questions.

I hope this helps?

Comment: Lightning speed! Thanks @hugo, I'll try and fiddle a little bit, C# and webparts are completely new to me, but this is a great start! Thanks again.

Comment: that looks great, @Hugo! I was thinking about creating a sample too, but you were first.